# $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/R$ is indiscrete.

Tags: general-topology

Define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $xRy$ iff $x — y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $R$ is an 
equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/R$ is indiscrete.

---

I have done that the given relation is equivalent but stuck on the 2nd part of the problem.can somebody help me please.thanks for your time

Comment: I think you need to show that every intervals like  $(a,b)$ contains members of every equivalence class regarding to $R$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $O \subset \mathbb{R}$. The image of $O$ in $\mathbb{R}/R$ is open iff $O+ \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\mathbb R/R$ being indiscrete means that $\mathbb R/R$ has only one nonempty open set, namely $\mathbb R/R$. To see this, let $U\subseteq \mathbb R/R$ open and non-empty, which means by definition of the quotient, that $V= \{x \in \mathbb R  \mid x/R \in U\}$is open in $\mathbb R$. As $U$ is non-empty, $V$ is also, choose $x\in \mathbb R$, $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq V$. Now use denseness of $\mathbb Q$ to construct for each $y \in \mathbb R$ an $q\in \mathbb Q$ with $y-q \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. Conclude $V = \mathbb R$ and hence $U = \mathbb R/R$.